# how to switch the page of stackwidget by mouse's hover event?

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

how to switch the page of stackwidget by mouse's hover event?

I try to use mouse'events and eventfilter on button, and successfully，but fail in this widget

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.